# Repositioning a display on a partially broken monitor

Tags: display, hardware-failure

This is what I am looking to do.
[image: This is what I am looking to do]

I have resized my monitor with the NVIDIA Control Panel, but I want to position my display in the top left of the monitor, but I am unsure of how to achieve this.

My monitor is a **Dell P2714H**, but when I go to reposition the display in the Display Settings, they're grayed out and inaccessible.

Thank you